# Help with understanding the inequality

Tags: inequality

I have found an upper-bound $\beta(a)$ (i.e., some expression involving the scalar $a$) such that the following holds:

$$ \beta(a) \geq \gamma(a) $$

for some other expression $\gamma(a)$ involving the scalar $a$.

**First Question:**
I would like to find the range of values for $a$ such that $ \gamma(a) \leq 1 $. Can I use $\beta(a) \leq 1$ to find range of $a$ such that $ \gamma(a) \leq 1 $?

**Second Question:** Can I use $\beta(a) \geq 1$ to find range of $a$ such that $ \gamma(a) \geq 1 $?

I am not able to see these unfortunately. Any intuitive examples to understand this would be appreciated.

Comment: Take $\gamma(a)=a^2$ and $\beta(a)=a^2+1$. See what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question:**
You can get a partial answer.
If $\beta(a) \leq 1$, then $\gamma(a)\leq 1$ since
$$ \gamma(a) \leq \beta(a) \leq 1.$$
However, there may be some values $a$ such that $\gamma(a)\leq 1$ but $\beta(a)>1$. For instance, if $\gamma(a)=a$ and $\beta(a)=a+1$, then $\beta(a)\leq 1$ for all $a\in(-\infty,0]$, but $\gamma(a)\leq 1$ for all $a\in(-\infty,1]$.

**Second question:**
No. If $\gamma(a)=0$ and $\beta(a)=a$, then $\beta(a)\geq 1$ for all $a\in[1,\infty)$, but $\gamma(a)\geq 1$ does not occur for any $a$.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, you can deduct from your inequality that $$\{a : \gamma(a)\leq 1\}\supseteq \{a : \beta(a)\leq 1\}$$ and for your second question, you know that $$\{a : \gamma(a)\geq 1\}\subseteq \{a : \beta(a)\geq 1\}$$ It's impossible to say more about these sets without more context, though.